# How can I properly access pictures hosted on google from my website?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, google-maps

Prior to writing this I have checked multiple threads but unfortunately nothing worked for what I would want to do.

Problem summary - I can't remotely access pictures that are hosted on google. Each time I get 403 error.

What I want is to import a custom map created via Google My Map. It works just fine but the only problem is with the pictures that are attached to the markers(custom places in map). The url of such image is like this:

https://doc-0o-b8-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/untrusted/hostedimage/...(etc)

Initially I wanted to download images during the importing so I could host them myself but couldn't do that(tried with php - file_get_contents and with cURL). In each case exactly the same outcome - 403 error.

```
$download = file_get_contents($image['src']);

$temp = 'image';

file_put_contents($temp, $download);

$file_data = getimagesize($temp);

$image_data = $file_data['mime'];

$image_type = explode('/', $image_data);

$extension = $image_type[1];

$filename = uniqid().'.'.$extension;

rename($temp, $filename);
```

Then I decided to just grab url and use it as img src on my website but the images are not showing and upon inspecting things in console I see that again they are blocked with 403 status. Tried to fix it using referrerpolicy="no-referrer" like suggested in the other thread here but this didn't work for me.

I have also noticed that the url changes - in database it is

https://doc-14-b8-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/...

while upon request it gets additional:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/refreshhostedimage?image=

```
GET
    https://www.google.com/maps/d/refreshhostedimage?image=https://doc-14-b8-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/untrusted/hostedimage/9avpvq94r6vtaqkua94s7osnog/1gi4vlth2r1htlo40bn4663sg8/1681729312250/SAFQ1ifJvKFuhLWIu6k2d2Vts9i4q4bn/02678364236970215753/5ACtvi-HSK4OcLlk_DqkMRk3QBAAAEx4FkNe76dO8q7TrlqF4hxLI-CvR8laYA5wjC_rjeCKMZTt-7_OotC6v27YfauAu-thquQJIEyb78Ak-6bsGKByVuiyyMcasH35iRSV6bmdNHIdmt3OOv_b_lRUFv10IpXHMn1XYxveaH-eQucLbj4jtwDJFIFIBZTitlUD3TFVsdHSWE4AOqrQyJyyCTw6Yml4hz5Ipj8ZgMRphGXw3vXM?session=0&fife

Status
403
Forbidden
VersionHTTP/3
Transferred1.34 kB (0 B size)
Referrer Policyno-referrer
Request PriorityLow

    alt-svc
        h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
    cache-control
        no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    content-encoding
        gzip
    content-security-policy
        script-src 'nonce-gR9uy9oHHNH4UMkGREnXXg' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /maps/d/cspreport
    content-type
        text/html; charset=utf-8
    cross-origin-opener-policy
        same-origin-allow-popups
    date
        Tue, 18 Apr 2023 11:05:46 GMT
    expires
        Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    p3p
        CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
    p3p
        CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
    pragma
        no-cache
    server
        ESF
    server-timing
        gfet4t7; dur=207
    set-cookie
        NID=511=VSKi-vl465owV7dxYA30KpIAOhK-vxK3UOYRrhnw5bCBzk8tybT08No9Bg4Fo5ecyXx_0EZ6TNOrTVG-XrIXfQ6yi9G85-bpZJahQoLgY7KPm8AlAHFD5zfxrdGLLd5-EI0SH1BnMAB9-DwK8VYE8PbywXsihwYieY7bSRuwrds; expires=Wed, 18-Oct-2023 11:05:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none
    set-cookie
        NID=511=g67_nFN3euSY9Zbm2FiZJ6B3Z5S9Zhuxj9Ne8lphLd3wZbcJgM_VM3QfwwABaZYzA8uXVP5tLadqXrztOrtZ_PtAKGVNFvD8E9tQXWv9KX5Xc1bLnoeD9CKsP4kMpeJ7_LT-5ho1PmZvbPrJdZnk-EAuzUqFq0UvHJnxgjllMZ8; expires=Wed, 18-Oct-2023 11:05:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none
    x-content-type-options
        nosniff
    x-xss-protection
        0
        
    Accept
        image/avif,image/webp,*/*
    Accept-Encoding
        gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language
        en-US,en;q=0.5
    Alt-Used
        www.google.com
    Connection
        keep-alive
    Host
        www.google.com
    Sec-Fetch-Dest
        image
    Sec-Fetch-Mode
        no-cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site
        cross-site
    TE
        trailers
    User-Agent
        Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0
```

I suspect that google is actively blocking my requests, perhaps I need to provide credentials or some API key?

I would like to know what is the best way to handle this issue as I'm out of ideas...

Comment: The 403 means the image files aren't public and (presumably) only the account which created them can view them. Google isn't a CDN

Comment: I don't know the Maps functionality intimately but possibly there is a way to publish images in such a way that they are publicly accessible, or perhaps you can change the permissions of the existing ones, or maybe you will need to try and fetch them via an authenticated request to the Maps API

Comment: You also have a typo: `$file_put_contents($temp, $download);` should be `file_put_contents($temp, $download);` (unless you have a variable called `$file_put_contents` that contains a function)

Comment: Yes, @M.Eriksson that was a typo, corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson)'s comments:

> The 403 means the image files aren't public and (presumably) only the account which created them can view them. Google isn't a CDN

> I don't know the Maps functionality intimately but possibly there is a way to publish images in such a way that they are publicly accessible, or perhaps you can change the permissions of the existing ones, or maybe you will need to try and fetch them via an authenticated request to the Maps API

I was so focused on finding correct function but I didn't think that it could be related with a permission level for a map itself.

When I set the map as publicly available the images are loading without any problems so google was actively blocking requests because my map was private.

Worth to mention in case somebody else will face similar issue.

Comment: @InSync - this seems like an answer to me: it was written by the OP and detailed what was done to fix the problem.